# How to remove a file permanently in Git without getting "WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged"?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have been googling and reading various posts around the net and I've tried:

`git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch Launcher\lib" --prune-empty -- --all`

and

`git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf Launcher\lib" --prune-empty -- --all`

All resulting in a:

> WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged

There are other clones of this repository and a central server also. I will push changes to the server, as I understand, others with clones just need to fetch and rebase (not merge)? Would it still work if they have made changes?

Comment: Did anything change after the filter branch?

Comment: No, filesystem is the same and I see the files in the history.

Comment: Is there a difference between `index-filter` and `tree-filter` versions of the command, other than speed, in terms of final repo history? Also what does the `--`, `--all` and `--prune-empty` do?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem, it was the path that was wrong. I changed this:

`Launcher\lib`

to this:

`Launcher/lib/`

and now it works ;)

Comment: Similarly, if you've moved the file with `git mv`, the old commits still refer to the old location, so you should `rm` that, not the new location (or run it with both).

Comment: faced the exact situation and solved in same way but got to this post after found the solution. But its good that you already answered your question, will be helpful for others. Conclusion is git on windows is not able to recognize \ between folder path.

Answer (score 8):

I'm gonna put this here as a future reference since I had the same problem:
If you use `cmder` (or other `ConEmu` flavors), use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Also wrap the path in quotes if you have some white space in your address:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
"git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 'server/bin/some file.txt'" \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

That was the problem when I got that error.