# Can't remove file from git commit

Tags: git, github, terminal

**How do I discard all git commits that haven't been pushed and then force git to not commit anything in the data/ directory?**

I'm trying to force overwrite all changes to a project stored on github from my c9.io project.  I accidentally git added some mongodb data files.  I tried to add the data/ directory to .gitignore. I pulled from github to get the updated .gitignore, however when I try and git push, these stubborn files in data/ are still staged for commit.  I also tried git reset, git rebase, git clean and [this](http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2013/fixing-the-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-mb-error/) where I changed dmpfile.sql to pi/data/node-login.1.

Please help I've been at this for hours and I'm really frustrated

```
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 150.22 KiB | 92 KiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: warning: File pi/data/local.0 is 64.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File pi/data/node-login.0 is 64.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: e6ade98208c08b634ed28aefea36dfbb
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File pi/data/node-login.1 is 128.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
To git@github.com:bobbyg603/goddard.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:bobbyg603/goddard.git'
```

.gitignore:

```
lib-cov
*.seed
*.log
*.csv
*.dat
*.out
*.pid
*.gz

data/

pids
logs
results

npm-debug.log
node_modules

.project
.settings
```

Thanks,
Bobby

Comment: show your **.gitignore** rule.

Comment: You linked to a page that talks about using `git filter-branch` to remove files from your history. This is the correct approach. What problems did you have with this process?

Comment: Thanks Chris! I must have made a typo the first time I tried.  I ran the command again and it appears to have worked :)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Thanks to Chris I was able to fix this by running the following:

> git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch  pi/data/node-login.0'
>
> git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch  pi/data/node-login.1'
>
> git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch  pi/data/local.0'

Comment: Be careful, it rewrites all the history.

Comment: Or use [The BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).  I've done it both ways, and BFG is faster but takes a bit more care to set up, whereas git filter-branch is a nice one-liner.

Comment: This didn't move tags across and now everything is duplicated.

Comment: I tried so many solutions and only this one worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: To expand on Sheraz's comment, in Windows make sure to have double quotes instead of single quotes, and if your path and/or file has spaces in the name, surround it by single quotes. So `git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 'path/with/spaces/in/file name.txt'"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33741936/6169534 . Also make sure you're in the right directory!

Comment: Guys , Is there affect on remote file ?

Comment: @Camit1dk I think when you push this to origin it completely deletes that file from history. Be careful!

Comment: Getting `Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged` after running this. Sigh, why is git so complicated..

Comment: Make sure to take care of all the unstaged changes otherwise you'll get `Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.`. You can for example commit those and then the code will run.

Answer (score 72):

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch FOLDERNAME" -- --all
```

replace FOLDERNAME with the file or folder you wish to remove from the given git repository.

Comment: I got another error about a dirty working directory. Fixed it by making sure my constantly updating jupyter checkpoints were ignored and my gitignore was committed then this worked.

Comment: It gives me error while pushing .. "error: failed to push some refs to https//..." and gives "hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind" . But when i pulled it gave lot of conflicts.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

```
git rm --cached name_of_a_giant_file
git rm --cached name_of_another_giant_file
git commit --amend -CHEAD
git push
```

Source: [Github Help: Working with large files](https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/user/articles/working-with-large-files/)

Comment: Nothing happening. After applying this though it reduced total number of file  but but after showing process 99% it stuck again. Any suggestion what I'm missing ?

Comment: @biscuit314 Please update the command: git commit --amend -CHEAD

Answer (score 7):

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/whaever' HEAD
```

This is a little bit simpler and it is a way to just remove and rewrite it from the history. That's the result

```
Rewrite 5ac3045254d33fc5bb2b9fb05dccbdbb986b1885 (61/62) (24 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
Ref 'refs/heads/features_X' was rewritten
```

Now, I can push

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the only method that worked for my particular case.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [BFG Repo Cleanner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) simple and fast, works like a charm