# Git rewrite history by running external tool on each commit

Tags: c#, git

We have a repo with several thousands of commits that uses a really old code convention we want to replace with the default Microsoft one. The easiest is to run a code formatting tool on the latest commit only, but this way we lose "blame" and the history gets harder to follow.
Can this be achieved by running the code formatting tool (in our case https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter) on each commit, thus preserving change history, and what version of filter-branch should we use?

Edit: turns out the tool I was about to use was crashing on some of the commits, so that's why filter-branch did not work for me and did not apply any changes to the commits

Comment: That means when you go back in history to see the state of the codebase at that time, you have a misleading picture. That seems problematic to me.

Comment: You probably could - though your git history will be completely rewritten. Any tags you have will be invalid and have to be remade as you go along...

Comment: The idea is only to reformat code so it is easier to read, without impacting functionality
@fredrik Yeah you are right that tags would need to be rebuilt, but it seems worth the hassle

Comment: Be aware that `git filter-branch` works by *extracting* each commit (physically so with `--tree-filter`) into a temporary directory, *not* the normal work-tree directory. You must point your reformatter to the temporary directory (the current directory of the process run by `git format-branch`).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the tree filter:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "CodeFormatter.exe"
```

Comment: Yeah this is the default filter-branch but due to some reason it passes OK for a small repo, but the commits are not changed afterwards. The command I'm using is

`git filter-branch --tree-filter '"PATHTO\CodeFormatter.exe" "PATHTO\Solution.sln"`

This should work in theory but only the latest commit is updated, as changes in the working directory

Comment: The warning I get is 
`WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged`
Even though the output of the formatter shows everything went fine

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240949/how-to-remove-a-file-permanently-in-git-without-getting-warning-ref-refs-head, could you please try using forward slashes?

Comment: I get it - the operation fails on some of the commits - the first one actually, since the .sln file does not exist, and the code formatting tool crashes

Comment: Does this work on Windows? git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -name '*.sln' -print0 | xargs -0 CodeFormatter.exe"

Answer (score 1):

```
git rebase --interactive --exec CodeFormatter.exe --root
```

I.e. perform an interactive rebase [executing the given command on every commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase--xltcmdgt).

Shorten the command to just

```
git rebase -i -x CodeFormatter.exe --root
```